# Typecheck when mapping some items in a sequence to None

Tags: scala, sequences

The following code traverses some list of nodes and creates `Paragraph` or `Heading` objects for some of the nodes:

```
  abstract class Element    
  case class Paragraph(node: Node) extends Element
  case class Heading(mainNode: Node, textNode: Node) extends Element

  val elements =
      parent.child.map(n =>
        if (n.label == "p") Paragraph(n)
        else if (n.label.matches("h\d")) Heading(n, n.child.head)
        else None)
```

Next, I would like to get rid of the `None` elements and pass `elements` to some function that requires `Seq[Element]`. However, the type of `elements` is `Seq[Product with Serializable]` rather than `Seq[Element]`. Why, and how can I make the type stronger?

Comment: What is the type of `child`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `collect` instead of `map` to keep only the elements you want:

```
val elements = parent.child.collect {
    case n if (n.label == "p") => Paragraph(n)
    case n if (n.label.matches("h\d")) => Heading(n, n.child.head))
}
```

Anything that isn't defined within the `PartialFunction` you pass to `collect` is discarded.

There's no reason to map to `None` if you're just going to discard the elements anyway. And if you *do* for some reason want to keep the `None` instances, then the others should be mapped to `Some[Element]` so that you'd have `Seq[Option[Element]`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and for the detailed and very helpful explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with m-z that `collect` is a great option here.  You might sometimes also choose to use `flatMap`, and return `Some` for the values you want, and `None` for the others.  Since `Option` is implicitly converted to an iterable, `flatMap` will flatten the list to what you want:

```
val elements = parent.child.flatMap(n =>
    if (n.label == "p") Some(Paragraph(n))
    else if (n.label.matches("h\d")) Some(Heading(n, n.child.head))
    else None)
```